# Guidance with ionic-settings usage

Tags: ionic-framework, setup-project

I'm trying to configure my app to use the [ionic-settings](https://github.com/ivandroid/ionic-settings) code.

My question is regarding the "Usage" section.
Where do I put the code listed in item #4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the next section (#5)

```
// INITIALIZATION IN CONFIG PHASE (USING PIN)
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionicSettings'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/main',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            resolve: {
                settings: function($ionicSettings, $ionicPopup) {
                    var settings = {
                        toggle1: {
                            type: 'toggle',
                            label: 'Toggle 1',
                            value: true
                        },
                        toggle2: {
                            type: 'toggle',
                            label: 'Toggle 2',
                            value: false
                        },
                        pin: {
                            type: 'pin',
                            label: 'PIN',
                            value: '',
                            onValid: function() {
                                $ionicPopup.alert({
                                    title: 'Success',
                                    template: 'Welcome!'
                                });
                            },
                            onInvalid: function($event, wrongPinValue) {
                                $ionicPopup.alert({
                                    title: 'Fail',
                                    template: 'Wrong pin: ' + wrongPinValue + '! Try again.'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return $ionicSettings.init(settings);
                }
            }
        })
});
// INITIALIZATION IN CONTROLLER (WITHOUT PIN)
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSettings) {
    $ionicSettings.init({
        awesomeSelection: {
            type: 'selection',
            values: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            label: 'Awesome Selection',
            value: 'two'
        },
        coolToggle: {
            type: 'toggle',
            label: 'Cool toggle',
            value: true
        }
    });
});
```